# ES5 not working in chrome, using Gulp

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gulp

I am using Gulp to compile/uglify javascript and then live reload browser.
Gulp is working fine, but when I run the JS in Chrome, I dont get any errors, but my code still isnt working.

I tried it in jsfiddle and it worked fine. Does anyone have a clue, what might cause this issue ?

I even tried turning off the compilation and let it run as ES6.

Here is my gulp file:

```
/**
*
* The packages we are using
*
**/
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var sass         = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync');
var prefix       = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var uglify       = require('gulp-uglify');
var babel        = require('gulp-babel');
var connect      = require('gulp-connect-php');




gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

/**
*
* Styles
* - Compile
* - Compress/Minify
* - Catch errors (gulp-plumber)
* - Autoprefixer
*
**/
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
  .pipe(prefix('last 2 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'Android 2', 'Firefox ESR'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

/**
*
* BrowserSync.io
* - Watch CSS, JS & HTML for changes
* - View project at: localhost:3000
*
**/
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init(['css/*.css', 'js/**/*.js', 'index.html'], {
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    }
  });
});


/**
*
* Javascript
* - Uglify
*
**/
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js-min'))
});



// Connect php

gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
  });
});

/**
*
* Default task
* - Runs sass, browser-sync, scripts and image tasks
* - Watchs for file changes for images, scripts and sass/css
*
**/
gulp.task('live', ['sass', 'scripts', 'connect-sync'], function () {
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('php/**/*.php').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});
```

Here is my JS:

```
class ExpandArticle {
  constructor () {
    this.getButtonOpen = document.getElementsByClassName("col-left__button-open");
    this.getButtonClose = document.getElementsByClassName("col-left__button-close");

    this.addEventListeners = this.addEventListeners.bind(this);
    this.expand = this.expand.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);

    if(this.getButtonOpen)
      this.addEventListeners();
  }

  expand (event) {
    let ID = event.target.id;

    this.getButtonOpen[ID].className += " hide";
    this.getButtonClose[ID].className = "col-left__button-close";
    document.getElementById("expand" + ID).className = "expand";
    document.getElementById("title" + ID).className = "move-up";
    document.getElementById("img" + ID).className = "col-left__img-open";
  }

  close (event) {
    let ID = event.target.id;

    document.getElementById("expand" + ID).className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("title" + ID).className = "";
    document.getElementById("img" + ID).className = "col-left__img-close";
    this.getButtonOpen[ID].className = "col-left__button-open";
    this.getButtonClose[ID].className += " hide";
  }

  addEventListeners () {
    let that = this;

    [].forEach.call(this.getButtonOpen, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', that.expand);
    }); 

    [].forEach.call(this.getButtonClose, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', that.close);
    });    
  }   
}

new ExpandArticle();
```

But as I said, it just wont work in Chrome.

Getting really frustrated..

Comment: You might be executing `new ExpandArticle` too soon. Try `window.onload = function() { new ExpandArticle() };`

Comment: This made the trick, but its strange, I thought that when I am using event listeners, that the timing of when the function is called, shouldnt apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when things work in `jsfiddle` but not elsewhere, you have a script that access the DOM before it is ready. `jsfiddle` has an option to indicate when your code should execute, but by default it executes it after the document has been loaded. So this can influence how the code behaves.

Inspecting your code, we see that the constructor accesses the DOM, for instance with this:

```
this.getButtonOpen = document.getElementsByClassName("col-left__button-open");
```

This will not fail if the DOM is not ready, but it will just return an empty node list into `this.getButtonOpen`, which explains you don't get any errors, but don't get any desired behaviour either.

So to solve this, do what `jsfiddle` does silently for you:

```
window.onload = function () {
    new ExpandArticle();
};
```

Also consider using the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which triggers sooner:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    new ExpandArticle();
});
```